# Calculate the standard deviation in R for a specific group of the dependent variable

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation from certain variables for different groups. In my dataset I have a 2 explanatory variables with a 0 or 1 outcome (CH and CH2). I would like to know the difference in the standard deviation of these two groups.

so far I am working with the following command. sample being the dataset and COM being one of the explanatory variables.

```
sd(sample$COM, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Is it possible to specify it for CH = 1?
And additionally for CH = 1 or CH2=1?

Thank you in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Hi Nienke, you can do it like sd(samples$COM[sample$CH==1]) and sd(samples$COM[sample$CH==1 | sample$CH2==1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using subset function:

```
with(subset(samples, subset=CH==1), 
     sd(COM)
    )
with(subset(samples, subset=CH==1 | CH2==1), 
     sd(COM)
    )
```

It's so much easier to read and you don't need to keep repeating the dataset$ stuff all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tapply function will do what you want:

```
tapply(sample$COM, sample$CH, sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) package.

using the mtcars dataset as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% 
  summarise(SD_disp = sd(disp),
            SD_hp = sd(hp))
```